# Receiving unwanted emails from launchpad

Tags: launchpad

I had clicked something in Launchpad, under impression i will receive answers by email, relevant to my question.

But now I am getting  a flood of completely irrelevant emails, hundreds a day, which i diverted to trash. But i can't find where to un-click this option, I have to frequently empty thousands of irrelevant emails from trash, which deletes other messages as well, the ones i might possibly want to recover. Thousands of messages can't be managed the "normal way", it's like finding needle in hundred haystacks.

Answer (score 5):

You can change your email settings at this URL:

- https://launchpad.net/people/+me/+editemails

More information here: https://help.launchpad.net/Bugs/Subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

What's your launchpad username?

You probably subscribed to receive all notifications for answers or bugs.
See, for example, https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pitivi/+question/157484
and the huge list of users who are `subscribed` by accident.

See https://launchpad.net/~/+participation
to see where you are subscribed to.